# YouTube App like UITableView

Tags: iphone

does anyone have a tutorial or some sample on how to make a UITableView like the YouTube iPhone App?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while it doesn't try to emulate the youtube app, this guide is a good idea of how to do most things:
[Here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)